# Javascript: How to count how often characters are in a given string and return them as numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, count, numbers

I am trying to count how often each individual characters is in a given string and return them as a number.

So for instance the lets take the string "HelloWorld".

> HELLOWORLD There is just one H - so 1 should be returned and H
>   deleted.
>
> ELLOWORLD There is one E - so 1 should be returned and E deleted.
>
> LLOWORLD There are three L - so 3 should be returned and all L
>   deleted.
>
> OWORD There are two O - so 2 should be returned and all O deleted.
>
> WRD There is just on of each characters - so 1 1 1 should be returned.

In the end I want all numbers to be concatenated so the result is:

1132111 (this can be either a string or a number).

Is this possible?

Thanks for reading and if you have any tip I am happy to read about it!

Comment: So what did you try to do to solve this homework/interview question? There are multiple ways to solve it.

Comment: For basic questions like this, we ask that you first take a crack at it, post your code, then we'll try to help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Is this possible" is usually a non-starter.  Unless you're talking about something where there's a hardware limitation or clear mutually-exclusive requirements, the answer is generally "yes".  What you're talking about is defining logic which takes input and produces output.  That's very possible.  The question then becomes... What have you tried?  If you don't know JavaScript, start with some tutorials.  If you don't know how to define the logic for what you're attempting, grab a pencil and paper and start working through the problem manually.  Define the steps to reach the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method with simple while loops

```js
function count(str){
 str = str.split('');
        //this will returned
 let result = ''
 let count = 1;
 while(str.length !== 0){
  count = 1;
                //while there is some duplicate of letter in str
  while(str.indexOf(str[0]) !== str.lastIndexOf(str[0])){
   count++;
                        //remove the last occurence of the duplicate
   str.splice(str.lastIndexOf(str[0]),1)
  }
                //after this all the duplicates of first letter are removed so we remove the first letter from str
  str.shift();
  result += count;
 }
 return result;
}
console.log(count("helloworld"));
```

Answer (score 0):

More cleaner way with reduce

```js
function occurrences(str) {
  str = str.split('');

  var occurrence = str.reduce((acc, cv) => {
    acc[cv] = ++acc[cv] || 1;
    return acc
  }, {})

  return Object.values(occurrence).join('')
}

console.log(occurrences('helloworld'))
```